# More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module

Tags: angular

in previous versions i have just been able to generate a new component like this...

```
ng g c modules/update-tables/containers/users-container
```

Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

then i tried...

```
ng g c containers/users-container --module=update-tables
```

Error: Specified module does not exist

then i tried...

```
ng g c containers/users-container --module UpdateTablesModule
```

Error: Specified module does not exist

[image]

Comment: I think you need to provide relative path to the module file

Answer (score 1):

You should specify relative path to your `*.module.ts` file from `/app` folder:

```
ng g c containers/users-container ./modules/update-tables/update-tables/update-tables.module.ts
```

You can also omit the `.module.ts` suffix:

```
ng g c containers/users-container ./modules/update-tables/update-tables/update-tables
```

It even works without the module name, then it will take the first one in given folder, so it might be better to specify it:

```
ng g c containers/users-container ./modules/update-tables/update-tables
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ran through this issue before. There is nothing stopping you from creating the module yourself. Llook at any existing one to see the pattern such as including @NgModule and all. For the file, create a file named users-container.module.ts. Then add it to the imports section in the app.module.ts (or wherever module you need to include it in) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the module using the --module parameter. For example, if the main module is app.module.ts, run this:

```
ng g c new-component --module app
```